# Rails 6 server just stopped compiling webpack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

I have a really weird thing happening.

I was working on this project on my development environment and when I used to start the Rails server,

It would compile webpack on the first browser request.

Now, all the sudden, this is not happening, causing all the javascript and style to fail and the app is not rendered properly.

The Rails server console does not even show the [Webpacker] Compiling… line

If I start the webpack-dev-server myself, it works. But for some reason the rails server has just stopped doing it on its own. I have changed the line webpack_compile_output: false to true in webpacker.yml but the rails server still doesn't show anything that has to do with Webpack.

It's really strange. I haven't added any gems or updated any versions of node or webpack. I did update Git globally on my machine from version 1.9 to version 2.24 but that's about it.

Any ideas?

Update: (As Requested, here is the content of my config/wenpacker.yml

```
default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  check_yarn_integrity: false
  webpack_compile_output: true

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  resolved_paths: []

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: false

  static_assets_extensions:
    - .jpg
    - .jpeg
    - .png
    - .gif
    - .tiff
    - .ico
    - .svg
    - .eot
    - .otf
    - .ttf
    - .woff
    - .woff2

  extensions:
    - .mjs
    - .js
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Verifies that correct packages and versions are installed by inspecting package.json, yarn.lock, and node_modules
  check_yarn_integrity: false
   # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
    hmr: false
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: false
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false

    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: '**/node_modules/**'


test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: true

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

Comment: Please share the contents of your config/webpacker.yml

Comment: Just added it to original post Thanks

Comment: In development, if Rails thinks the webpack-dev-server is running, it won't trigger compilation. See if there's a process still hanging around listening on 3035 (your dev server port). On my Mac, I would run `lsof -nP -i4TCP:3035 | grep LISTEN`.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't appear to be running in the background. This one has me puzzled. I remember maybe about 1-2 weeks ago this was still working. I would start my Rails server and then at the first browser request, I would see the webpack compiling. This is not happening anymore. Really strange

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Experiencing this as well. *Typically* when running `rails s` you'll see something like this:

```
Started GET "/react_test/hello" for ::1 at 2020-05-15 16:54:29 -0700

Processing by ReactTestController#hello as HTML
  Rendering react_test/hello.html.erb within layouts/application

[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
```

If you make a change to a `js` (or `css`/`scss`) that are part of your webpack resources:

```
Processing by ReactTestController#hello as HTML
  Rendering react_test/hello.html.erb within layouts/application
[Webpacker] Compiling...
[Webpacker] Compiled all packs in /Users/foo/public/packs
[Webpacker] Hash: 1ea802b336ed3c771c61
Version: webpack 4.43.0
Time: 4844ms

... truncated for brevity (a list of assets, size, etc)
```

At some point, all of this stops - and you'll "have" to run *both* `rails s` *and* `./bin/webpack-dev-server` *manually*. So far, what I've noticed is that this is triggered when you run `webpack-dev-server` - e.g. when updating `config/webpacker.yml` - it does say it on that file itself in a note:

> `# Note: You must restart bin/webpack-dev-server for changes to take effect`

---

Try this *workaround*:

1. Stop `Rails server` and `webpack-dev-server`
2. Make some (temporary) change to your `/app/javascript/packs/application.js` file

   - e.g. comment out an import: `//import 'bootstrap'`
3. Restart `rails s` (**only**, *not* `webpack-dev-server`)
4. This will error out - because it's missing what was commented out (in this example `bootstrap`
5. Undo/uncomment the temporary change
6. Reload the page - hopefully, it should be good (Webpack compiles, etc).

I think (guess) it's some caching/sync issue that is "fixed/(reset?)" by making some change to `application.js`

Hth...

Comment: Thank you! It was super-frustrating hitting this issue right out of the gate. As a note, I just added a `console.log()` statement to my `app/javascript/packs/application.js` file and did what you said. Worked great!

Answer (score 5):

If webpacker stops responding to changes in application.scss or application.js, run this command in terminal:

```
rails webpacker:install
```

Comment: this works like a charm for me, also as I use vue, I have to run this command to:
rails webpacker:install:vue

Answer (score 2):

So, I actually ran into this today and after reading this question and doing some additional debugging, I realized the Rails Webpacker was failing because I had another project already running Webpacker and that confused the Rails version.

Shutting down the other Webpacker and restarting the Rails server immediately fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This drove me nuts when trying to stimulus reflex. This worked for me (although then had another Stimiuls Reflex issue with `ActionCable connection is not open!` thereafter which was progress.

1. In terminal execute `rails dev:cache` which will likely disable caching
2. Run your `rails server`
3. Thereafter re-run `rails dev:cache` in terminal (after shutting rails server).

In `environments/development.rb` the relevent config is:

```
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.action_controller.enable_fragment_cache_logging = true

  config.cache_store = :memory_store
  config.public_file_server.headers = {
    'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=#{2.days.to_i}",
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

My case was that I changed my version of `node` using `nvm`.
When everything stopped compiling, I forgot that switching my version simply uninstalled `yarn` which is normal, because I'm using another `node`/`npm` image and since `yarn` was installed globally by `npm`...
So:

1. Run `bin/rails webpacker:install`, it will say: "Yarn not installed. Please download and install Yarn from https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/
   Exiting!"
2. Reinstall yarn using `npm i -g yarn`
3. Run your belove `bin/rails s` command, and you're done

**Note**: you'll see again [**Webpacker**] doing its job in your terminal ✅

Answer (score 0):

I had an isse with webpacker compilation not running in the test environment on a project I hadnt touch in a while.
`bundle update webpacker` solved the issue. Weirdly, reverting to the old `Gemfile.lock` also works now so I dont know exactly what the issue was.